# AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup") while using Firebase with GoogleAppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, android-studio, firebase

I am Using Google App Engine to connect to Firebase but it is throwing an Exception. I am following the steps mentioned at:

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio

Although the libraries it references have since been updated, so I'm running newer versions of the dependencies:

```
    /** libraries for using firebase on the GoogleAppEngine */
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.31'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.5.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'
```

Also instead of creating `App Engine Java Servlet Module` i have created `App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging` because it makes easier to add GCM feature and i have manually created the servlet (Please note that the Servlet works fine without Firebase statement)

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>GOOGLE_CONSOLE_PROJECT_ID</application>
    <version>1</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>

    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    <property name="gcm.api.key" value="YOUR_KEY_HERE"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

It crashes when i create Firebase reference:

```
final Firebase usersLocation = new Firebase(Constants.FIREBASE_URL_USERS);
```

**Exception:**

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
        at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
        at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
        at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:55)
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:136)
        at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
        at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
        at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
        at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:675)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It started to work when i changed the version for `appengine-api-1.0-sdk` from `1.9.31` to `1.9.26`

**UPDATE**

I tried it with `1.9.31` and i see that it is working fine with that too. I am not sure why it was not working at first attempt.

I am keeping this thread open so that it can be helpful for others facing similar problem.

Comment: Google/Firebase engineer here. Thanks for the update. We're investigating what is causing this. Can you reach out to firebase-support@google.com?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks. What do you want me to send via Email?

Comment: Mostly so that we can reach out directly to you in case we need some more info. It's also fine if you'd prefer to just keep it here.

Comment: Sure. I have sent an email.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you didn't have version 31 deployed?
I can successfully run against appengine-api-1.0-sdk 1.9.31:

```
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.31'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.5.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'
```

The symptom you describe definitely describes what happens when firebase cannot detect a ThreadManager (which could be caused by either the api changing or not deployed).  But I am unable to reproduce the problem on my end and I've verified the api hasn't changed from 26-->31.

Comment: It may be something with the GCM sample that could prevent 1.9.31 loading?

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, It is working fine with `1.9.31` as well.